# customized symfony 3 form template

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

I tried to create a customized theme form symfony_3 form.

```
path: app/Resources/views/form
```

And I set the form as current theme

```
$view['form']->setTheme($form, array('app/Resources/views/form'));?>
```

But that does not work and the system calls the default symfony form theme. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

you could try define the form theming globaly in your config.yml as explained in this [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/form_themes.html#global-form-theming) or locally like this [other doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html):

Hope it helps